# Prevent modal close on asp:textbox enter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to prevent my modal from closing when keypress enter is entered in my modal asp textbox.

I have tried to wrap the textbox in another update panel and use an asynchronous postback trigger on textchanged, but thats not quite what I'm looking for. I am trying to create a text entry part which only updates when keypress enter is pressed and not when the text changes, I have also tried adding data-dismiss="modal" to the textbox itself like other pages have suggested, but this just means when I click on the textbox it shuts the modal.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd_mdl_console" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Ryan Console-->
        <div class="modal fade" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="mdl_console" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog2" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content _dev_console">
                    <div class="modal-header _dev_console">
                        <h5 class="modal-title pull-left" id="H1" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3" Text="DEV CONSOLE"></asp:Label></h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="panel-heading _dev_console">
                            <asp:Literal ID="devbox_line_5" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Literal>
                            <asp:Literal ID="devbox_line_4" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Literal>
                            <asp:Literal ID="devbox_line_3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Literal>
                            <asp:Literal ID="devbox_line_2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Literal>
                            <asp:Literal ID="devbox_line_1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Literal>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd_mdl_txt" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Devbox" class="form-control _dev_console" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>

                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-heading _dev_console">
                            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer _dev_console">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        <%--                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="lnk_go_Click" class="btn btn-success" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Text="Create"></asp:Button>--%>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary _dev_console" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following snippet to disable enter in textboxes. This also prevents triggering of a form post when pressing enter inside a textbox. It might work for preventing the closure of the modal also.

```
$('input').keypress(function (e) {
    return e.keyCode !== 13;
});
```

If you want to disable the enter in the modal only you could do something like this

```
$('.modal-body input').keypress(function (e) {
    return e.keyCode !== 13;
});
```